# recovering of time series in SSA

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, svd, time-series

i am trying to reconstruct time series from SSA  ,because according to this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_spectrum_analysis

there is procedure

```
4th step: Diagonal averaging.
```

i have   with started following code

```
clear all;
  B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
  n=length(B);
  l =input('Give the size of the interval: ' );% Number of columns in the Data matrix
   m=n-l+1;%number of rows in the Data matrix
 X = zeros(m,l);
  for i=1:m
        X(i,:)=B(i:i+l-1);
  end;
  [U E V]=svd(X);
```

now  which procedure should i make?i should choose some   eigenvalues right?from example let us consider following code

```
>> E=E(:);
    >> stem(E);
```

[image]

in this case  i should  choose  first four eigenvalue right?what i would like  would be if i  will indicate starting index of eigenvalue and ending point of eigenvalue and i will reconstruct time series in these range,how can i do it?please help me